# How to approve Token to self-deployed contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

My ultimate purpose is to swap some tokens across `pancakeswap` `babyswap` `apeswap` atomicly. So I build a contract(called ContractA) to run a bunch of swaps in a transaction. I transfer some USDT token into ContractA. But ContractA is not approved to transfers USDT by the USDT contract.

I known how to `approve` Metamask address to transfer USDT, but how to do it for a Contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to control an ERC20 token from a smart contract, first you need to create an instance of it. To do that, first you need to import ERC20 to your contract, and then just create an ERC20 type function giving it the token address you want to manage. It would be something like this:

```
// Some code...
import "@openzeppelin/contract/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

// Some more code...
contract exampleContract {
    // Example of an ERC20 token instance
    ERC20 USDTToken = ERC20("USDT Contract Address Here");

    // Approve USDT
    USDTToken.approve(address(this), _amount);
}
```

Then you will be able to manage the token, always following the ERC20 standard, as you want.

Hope you find this information useful :)

Comment: I just managed it. But I wonder where did code of `pancakeswap` call `approve` to allow swapping USDT out of its pool.

Comment: I have not made a deep look into pancakeswap code, but I think it implements a pair factory that manages all the ERC20 transfers. It may work with the transfer() function, which doesn't require an approval